# Need help in SQL and Sequel involving inner join and where/filter

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

Need help transfer sql to sequel:

SQL:

```
SELECT table_t.curr_id FROM table_t
INNER JOIN table_c ON table_c.curr_id = table_t.curr_id 
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_b.bic = table_t.bic
WHERE table_c.alpha_id = 'XXX' AND table_b.name='Foo';
```

I'm stuck in the sequel, I don't know how to filter, so far like this:

```
 cid= table_t.select(:curr_id).
                    join(:table_c, :curr_id=>:curr_id).
                    join(:table_b, :bic=>:bic).
                    filter( ????? )
```

Answer with better idiom than above is appreciated as well.Tnx.

**UPDATE:**

I have to  modify a little to make it works

```
cid = DB[:table_t].select(:table_t__curr_id).
  join(:table_c, :curr_id=>:curr_id).
  join(:table_b, :bic=>:table_t__bic). #add table_t or else ERROR: column table_c.bic does not exist
  filter(:table_c__alpha_id => 'XXX',
         :table_b__name => 'Foo')
```

without filter,

```
cid = DB[:table_t].select(:table_t__curr_id).
                    join(:table_c, :curr_id=>:curr_id, :alpha_id=>'XXX').
                    join(:table_b, :bic=>:table_t__bic, :name=>'Foo')
```

btw I use pgsql 9.0

Comment: 'SEQUEL' was the old name, nowadays we call it 'SQL' :)

Comment: I think he means SQL, some people pronouce it as "sequel"

Comment: i dont want to open new question, just want to know how to make the last code above sql injection proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the pure Sequel way:

```
cid = DB[:table_t].select(:table_t__curr_id).
  join(:table_c, :curr_id=>:curr_id).
  join(:table_b, :bic=>:bic).
  filter(:table_c__alpha_id => 'XXX',
         :table_b__name => 'Foo')
```

Note that you can also do this without a WHERE, since you are using INNER JOIN:

```
cid = DB[:table_t].select(:table_t__curr_id).
  join(:table_c, :curr_id=>:curr_id, :alpha_id=>'XXX').
  join(:table_b, :bic=>:bic, :name=>'Foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can always use something like

```
.filter('table_c.alpha_id = ? AND table_b.name = ?', 'XXX', 'Foo')
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing to remember is that Sequel is plenty happy to let you use raw SQL. If you find it easier to express the query as SQL go ahead, just be sure to comment it so you can find it later. Then you can return to that line and adjust it so it's taking advantage of Sequel's awesomeness.

Try to avoid anything that is specific to a particular DBM though, because you'll be reducing portability which is one of the big reasons for using an ORM to generate the queries.